# checkbox - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox named cbSelct. In  a botton_click event i wrote

`cbSelect.Checked=true`

is the above code in the code behind page causes for a cbSelected_CheckedChanged event?

I created a new website and place a checkbox named cbSelect and a button.

```
protected void cbSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("testMessage ");
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cbSelect.Checked = !cbSelect.Checked;
}
```

I put a break point inside cbSelect_CheckedChanged event. Now according to the answers i got below, i understand that , if i clicked button it should break on cbSelect_CheckedChanged function. But i think cbSelect_CheckedChanged event is  not firing  while clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its affect CheckedChanged  event.Before that you must use/create that event.

**EDIT**

make the `AutoPostBack property` of checkbox to `true`

**EDIT**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cbSelect.Checked = !cbSelect.Checked;
cbSelect_CheckedChanged(cbSelect,  e);


}
```

Comment: please look on my edited question . I tested what u told . But its not working

Comment: @Shameer:First ensure  `cbSelect_CheckedChanged` event is correct or not for that take `property window` of `cbSelect` , click  `events` button and click on  `CheckedChanged` in list .

Comment: thanks for reply .yeah . its correct . i cross checked it. i can debug while changing checkbox manually. My question is if i change the check box.checked in codebehind, is it still call cbSelect_CheckedChanged

Comment: @Shameer:yes  and AutoPostBack property is true

Comment: autopostback protperty of check box is true .but its not working for me :(

Comment: how you changed check box.checked in codebehind pls add code.

Comment: i already added the code in my question . cbSelect.Checked = !cbSelect.Checked; . I can see the changes in each post back after clicking the button

Comment: Now its working. :) . So without that line it not fire cbSelect_CheckedChanged event, right??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will cause the cbSelected_CheckedChanged event to be fired but only if you have defined a cbSelected_CheckedChanged event.

You can try it -

```
private void cbSelected_CheckedChanged (Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   //your code
}
```

Place a break point here and debug your code. You will find that the cbSelected_CheckedChanged  event will be fired.

Comment: please look on my edited question . I tested what u told . But its not working

Comment: In that case, set the AutoPostBack property to true. Vyas got it right. It should work.